# svchost termsvcs Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, virtual-machine, hyper-v, rds, windows-server-2012-r2

It seems like we have a memory leak in the termsvcs process of our RDS farm which occasionally occurs on a random machine in our farm. We have 10 session hosts on Windows Server 2012 R2 with current patch level who all serve around 20 to 30 users.

In this screenshot you can see the CPU and RAM load. Notice the steady drop in memory within the last 24 hours (http:// removed due to lack of reputation): i.imgur.com/dz11fPz.png

Here you can see the process in question with a very high value in Private Bytes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHX0i.png - and in comparison the same process on a healthy session host with the same configuration and roughly the same amount of users connected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKdf6.png

Notice the difference the Private Bytes.

Does anyone else experience something similar?
It seemingly started a week ago. So maybe related to a patch day.

Comment: I have similar issue, did you find the cause of this issue?

Comment: Currently we have all our 2012 R2 machines on a current patch level and the problem seems to be gone. Maybe a patch in the last few months fixed it. Microsoft support just told us to wait for the next update for months...

Comment: I just witnessed the same on one of our fully updated 2012R2 RDS Hosts. There are 20 Hosts working fine, this single one even had a Bluescreen after exhausting all RAM and SWAP. Emptying Working Sets halved RAM usage. Culprit is: TermService (termsvcs): Memory is Mapped: Reserved but not commited. Looks like a bug in RDPUDD (The UMRDP Display Driver) overallocating.